# pd.read_html not working for mutliple urls. IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-3.8

For the life of me I cannot figure this out. I have been scraping some SEC filings in a loop and want to scrape tables on the web page into a dataframe. The majority of the URLs work but a few URLs are not working. I tried to inspect the actual HTML to look for differences between the ones that worked and didn't work but my understanding of HTML is not the greatest.

```
import pandas as pd
url =  'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/0000892534/000117891307002012/zk74243.htm'
df = pd.read_html(url, flavor  = 'lxml')
```

the error it spits out is always the same for the problematic urls.

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-784175815486> in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.read_html(url, flavor  = 'lxml')

C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py in read_html(io, match, flavor, header, index_col, skiprows, attrs, parse_dates, thousands, encoding, decimal, converters, na_values, keep_default_na, displayed_only)
   1088         )
   1089     _validate_header_arg(header)
-> 1090     return _parse(
   1091         flavor=flavor,
   1092         io=io,

C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py in _parse(flavor, io, match, attrs, encoding, displayed_only, **kwargs)
    915     for table in tables:
    916         try:
--> 917             ret.append(_data_to_frame(data=table, **kwargs))
    918         except EmptyDataError:  # empty table
    919             continue

C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py in _data_to_frame(**kwargs)
    791     # fill out elements of body that are "ragged"
    792     _expand_elements(body)
--> 793     tp = TextParser(body, header=header, **kwargs)
    794     df = tp.read()
    795     return df

C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in TextParser(*args, **kwds)
   2221     """
   2222     kwds["engine"] = "python"
-> 2223     return TextFileReader(*args, **kwds)
   2224 
   2225 

C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    893             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    894 
--> 895         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    896 
    897     def close(self):

C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1145                     ' "python-fwf")'.format(engine=engine)
   1146                 )
-> 1147             self._engine = klass(self.f, **self.options)
   1148 
   1149     def _failover_to_python(self):

C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, **kwds)
   2308             self.num_original_columns,
   2309             self.unnamed_cols,
-> 2310         ) = self._infer_columns()
   2311 
   2312         # Now self.columns has the set of columns that we will process.

C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _infer_columns(self)
   2691                 columns = [names]
   2692             else:
-> 2693                 columns = self._handle_usecols(columns, columns[0])
   2694         else:
   2695             try:

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here are some other URLs giving me issues.

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/0001119774/000117891309002587/zk97422.htm
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/0001158780/000117891309002357/zk97328.htm

Comment: Are there any that are not giving you issues? What is different?

Comment: What table do you want to read from that URL?

Answer (score 1):

This might not be a full answer, but i just signed up earlier today, and aren't allowed to do comments, so I'm sorry in advance.

It looks like it's an issue with the tables on the page. Several of them have rows (`tr`) with empty headers (`th`), and no data-fields (`td`).

If you look at: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/0001119774/000117891309002587/zk97422.htm

This is the first table it finds is:

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
<tbody><tr valign="Bottom">
     <th><font face="Times New Roman" size="1"></font></th>
     <th><font face="Times New Roman" size="1"></font></th></tr>
<tr valign="Bottom">
     <th><font face="Times New Roman" size="1"></font></th>
     <th><font face="Times New Roman" size="1"></font></th></tr>
<tr valign="Bottom">
     <th><font face="Times New Roman" size="1"></font></th>
     <th><font face="Times New Roman" size="1"></font></th></tr>
<tr valign="Bottom">
     <th><font face="Times New Roman" size="1"></font></th>
     <th><font face="Times New Roman" size="1"></font></th></tr>
<tr valign="Bottom">
     <th><font face="Times New Roman" size="1"></font></th>
     <th><font face="Times New Roman" size="1"></font></th></tr>
<tr valign="Bottom">
     <td width="50%" align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2">PROSPECTUS SUPPLEMENT</font></td>
     <td width="50%" align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2">Filed Pursuant to Rule 424(b)(5)&nbsp;</font></td></tr>
<tr valign="Bottom">
     <td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2">(To Prospectus dated August 11, 2009)</font></td>
     <td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2">Registration No. 333-161241&nbsp;</font></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

The first 5 rows there doesn't have any `td` fields, and no header text either.
I tried saving that table to a local file, and then running `read_html` on that file, which gave me the same error. If i remove those first 5 rows that only have empty headers, then it works:

```
[                                       0                                 1
0                  PROSPECTUS SUPPLEMENT  Filed Pursuant to Rule 424(b)(5)
1  (To Prospectus dated August 11, 2009)       Registration No. 333-161241]
```

I'm not used to working with Pandas, so i'm not sure if there's a way to force it to skip those empty `tr` elements.

I also found this question:
[pandas read_html clean up before or after read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349215/pandas-read-html-clean-up-before-or-after-read)

While that question was a different issue, it might be it's better to try doing this with something like BeautifulSoup? It seems like Pandas doesn't handle this page very well. Also based on this answer:
[pandas read_html clean up before or after read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349215/pandas-read-html-clean-up-before-or-after-read#comment89913606_51466451)
which is very much true for the above table as well. HTML-wise, it's very different from what is actually displayed on the page.